# Image alignment in columns

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of images aligned using the below CSS but they are being placed top to bottom.  How do I align them left to right?

In other words:

1|2|3|4

5|6|7|8

vs

1|3|5|7

2|4|6|8

```
#photos {
   line-height: 0;
   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}
#photos img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

This is from the turtorial:  http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: That's the point of the CSS trick is to stack them vertically to eliminate the white space. If you know how they're going to be stacked, just change the order in which they are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If you are really stuck on using HTML5 you should consider the fact that this won't work in all browsers, or all browser versions. If you are simply trying to make a block of images with no seams and have them stack in a row see the following.

```
  <style type="text/css">
        #photos {
            float:left;
            width:800px;
        }
        .imageItem{
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="photos">
        <img class="imageItem" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7136/7733019900_c671c8d393_m.jpg" />
        <img class="imageItem" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7136/7733019900_c671c8d393_m.jpg" />
        <img class="imageItem" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7136/7733019900_c671c8d393_m.jpg" />
        <img class="imageItem" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7136/7733019900_c671c8d393_m.jpg" />
        <img class="imageItem" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7136/7733019900_c671c8d393_m.jpg" />
        <img class="imageItem" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8426/7733031344_0762136432_m.jpg"/>
        <img class="imageItem" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8426/7733031344_0762136432_m.jpg"/>
        <img class="imageItem" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8426/7733031344_0762136432_m.jpg"/>
        <img class="imageItem" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8426/7733031344_0762136432_m.jpg"/>
        <img class="imageItem" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8426/7733031344_0762136432_m.jpg"/>
    </div>
</body>
```